# Containerized server application failing to connect to MySQL databases

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, kubernetes, node-mysql2

I'm trying to connect my server code running as a Docker container in our Kubernetes cluster (hosted on Google Container Engine) to a Google Cloud SQL managed MySQL 5.7 instance. The issue I'm running into is that every connection is being rejected by the database server with `Access denied for user 'USER'@'IP' (using password: YES)`. The database credentials (username, password, database name, and SSL certificates) are all correct and work when connecting via other MySQL clients or the same application running as a container on a local instance.

I've verified that all credentials are the same on the local and the server-hosted versions of the app and that the user I'm connecting with has the wildcard `%` host specified. Not really sure what to check next here, to be honest...

An edited version of the connection code is below:

```
let connectionCreds = {
    host: Config.SQL.HOST,
    user: Config.SQL.USER,
    password: Config.SQL.PASSWORD,
    database: Config.SQL.DATABASE,
    charset: 'utf8mb4',
};

if (Config.SQL.SSL_ENABLE) {
    connectionCreds['ssl'] = {
        key: fs.readFileSync(Config.SQL.SSL_CLIENT_KEY_PATH),
        cert: fs.readFileSync(Config.SQL.SSL_CLIENT_CERT_PATH),
        ca: fs.readFileSync(Config.SQL.SSL_SERVER_CA_PATH)
    }
}

this.connection = MySQL.createConnection(connectionCreds);
```

Additional information: the server application is built in Node using the [mysql2](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2) library to connect to the database. There are no special firewall rules in place that are causing network issues, and that's confirmed by the fact that the library IS connecting, but failing to authenticate.

Comment: if you are sure about firewall and port are enabled in your security group then there is an issue in your code may be in the parameter.it would be good if you share your connection code

Comment: @Adiii I've added the connection code above in case it's helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After setting up [Cloud SQL Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-container-engine) I managed to figure out what the actual error was: somewhere between the secret and the pod configuration an extra newline was being added to the database name, causing any connection attempt to fail. With the proxy set up this was made clear because there was an actual error message to that effect displayed.

(notably all of my logging around the credentials that I was using to validate that the credentials were accurate didn't explicitly display the newline and was disguised by the fact that the console display added line breaks to wrap the display, and it happened to line up exactly with where the database name ended)

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the documentation on https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-container-engine ?

In Container Engine, you need to set up a Cloud SQL Proxy container alongside your application pod and talk to it. The Cloud SQL Proxy will then make the actual call to Cloud SQL service.

If the container worked locally, I assume you have Application Default Credentials set on your development machine. It could be failing because those credentials are not on your container as a Service Account file. Try configuring a Service Account file, or create your GKE cluster with `--scopes` argument that gives your instances access to Cloud SQL.

Comment: I have read that documentation yes; but I'm fairly confident that a proxy isn't necessary because I can connect to the server without issue; the connection doesn't fail until the authentication step. Additionally I already have a server set up and communicating with another cloud SQL instance with identical security settings (allows SSL only from 0.0.0.0/0)

Comment: Okay, this didn't actually solve the problem but after setting up CloudSQL proxy I found the actual issue because it provides significantly more useful error messages.